# How do I get the value of an input field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the inner html value of a field and that works fine but when I try to retrieve it it fails.

My code:

```
            var butId = buttonPressed.getAttribute('id');

            $('#will'+butId).remove();
            $('#hidDelete').html(butId);     //THIS WORKS FINE
            var temp = $('#hidDelete').html();   //THIS DOESNT
            alert (temp);      //THIS PRINTS NOTHING
```

My input field:

```
           <input id="hidDelete" type="hidden" name="hidDelete"/>
```

Can anyone see whats wrong with it?

Comment: Are you sure a (self-closing) `<input />` tag would have inner HTML? It makes sense to me that it doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try `$('#hidDelete').val()` instead of `html()`

Answer (score 1):

`$().html()` is for accessing content from within a pair of tags, eg. `<div>foo</div>`. You want `$().val()`. That's for getting/setting the 'value' of `input` fields.

Comment: I can only accept one answer so I'll go with the first one but I'll give you an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#hidDelete').html(butId);     //THIS WORKS FINE
var temp = $('#hidDelete').html();   //THIS DOESNT
alert (temp);      //THIS PRINTS NOTHING
```

Instead of above use below

```
$('#hidDelete').val(butId);     
var temp = $('#hidDelete').val();  
alert (temp);
```

in jquery selector.html is used to get the inner html of elements. This should not be used for inputs type elements.

Comment: I have fixed your formatting and removed the **bold** highlighting on the sentence ....

Comment: Ok, I have given that intentionally.

Comment: I can only accept one answer so I'll go with the first one but I'll give you an upvote :)

Comment: Not a problem @mixkat. Thanks.